# Number of days between two column values on separate rows

Tags: mysql

I'm experienceing a challenge that I can't seem to get my head around, not that there's any experience rattling round in there. I have some auto repair/spray bays and I want to know how many days that are not in use. Here's a simple table example shwoiung just one bay from a total of 20. I will always query just one bay at a time unless there's a clever way of doing multiple:

```
bayID |   sDate    |   eDate
------+------------+------------
1     | 2014-09-06 | 2014-09-13
1     | 2014-09-17 | 2014-09-21
1     | 2014-09-27 | 2014-09-30
1     | 2014-10-30 | 2014-10-13
```

I've been reading up on Datediff but admit don't really understand the ins and out of it or mySQL. My question is how can I get the number of days between the first eDate and the second sDate, the second eDate and the... etc etc... sratching my head and aching with flu I look forward to any help given... Sorry, not a massive techie so answers in long English if possible... This is what I'm lloking for:

```
bayID |   sDate    |   eDate     availFor
------+------------+------------+---------
1     | 2014-09-06 | 2014-09-13      3
1     | 2014-09-17 | 2014-09-21      5
1     | 2014-09-27 | 2014-09-30      0
1     | 2014-10-30 | 2014-10-13
```

Comment: You're visibly trying to use MySQL, but if you wanted to get the detail of these time periods in order, you could achieve this with [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) (e.g. LEAD or LAG in this case) with an RDBMS that supports it, such as PostgreSQL or SQL Server.

Comment: This does sound like a solution but its passing over at great altitude I'm afraid. I will look into this though, in the hope that it makes some sense..

Comment: Did you mean `2014-09-30` instead of `2014-10-30` do get availFor=0? There's also an issue between start/end. If you count only 3 days between `2014-09-13` and `2014-09-17`, this means there should be -1 day between `2014-09-30` and `2014-09-30` (assuming that what you meant).

Comment: It looks like you got a suitable answer for MySQL. If you ever feel like looking into a solution that uses Window Functions, [here is SQLFiddle showing a solution using PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/70b01/1). The key difference is in `LEAD(sDate) OVER (PARTITION BY bayId ORDER BY sDate)`, which will create a pseudo column using the next sDate for that bay, with all the rows ordered by sDate. I'm fairly sure this should be more efficient than doing a subquery looking for the min every time, but it probably doesn't matter if you don't have too many rows.

Comment: Bruno, really appreciate your suggestions and its good to bounce a few things round, but I really have my plate/head full just trying to get my head around MySQL and PHP. For me at least, this is not easy.. any help or guidance would be warmly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the time periods are not ordered, you can get a result by calculating the overall duration and subtracting the durations when they are in use.  Here is an example:

```
select bayid,
       min(sdate) as firstsdate, max(edate) as lastedate,
       sum(datediff(edate, sdate)) as daysinuse,
       datediff(max(edate), min(sdate)) - sum(datediff(edate, sdate)) as DaysNotInUse
from bays b
group by bayId;
```

This gives you the days not in use between the first and last days the bay has been used.

EDIT:

That is an entirely different question.  You can answer it with a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*,
       datediff((select min(sdate)
                 from bays b2
                 where b2.bayId = b.bayId and b2.sdate >= b.edate
                ), edate) - 1 as DaysFreeBetweenBookings
from bays b;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply... am I right in saying this will just give me the total of 'daysInUse' and daysNotIn'? I'm looking for indivdial days between bookings so I can advise customer thatbay 1 is available for 3 whole days before the next customer turns up... I've edited my question to be more clear but if this is the answer I am so relieved

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion generated on my part but what you have just suggested works perfectly. I'm so grateful. If I had the credits to vote for you I would.... Enjoy the rest of your day Gordon.